# How `lm()` behaves when we remove intercept with multiple categorical predictors

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm, mixed-models

I have two binary predictors (`name` & `Treat`). I remove the intercept from the entire model (`value ~ name*Treat-1`).

Thus, I expect `lm()` not to take any category from any of my binary predictors as a reference category.

For predictor `name` my expectation matches the output (i.e., no category of `name` is taken as reference category).

BUT for my second binary predictor (i.e., `Treat`) one of its categories (i.e., `"Treat-0.5"`) has again been taken as reference category.

I wonder how `lm()` behaves when we remove intercept with multiple categorical predictors?

```
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/mv.l.csv')

dat$Treat <- factor(dat$Treat)

lm(value ~ name*Treat-1,data = dat)

coef(summary(m))

                   Estimate Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
nameY1          45.69318724  0.5132694 89.02378209 0.000000e+00
nameY2          45.97807164  0.5132694 89.57882078 0.000000e+00
Treat0.5         8.72325383  0.7258726 12.01760985 6.540707e-32
nameY2:Treat0.5 -0.09756526  1.0265389 -0.09504293 9.242927e-01
```

I expected the output to be:

```
                     Estimate Std. Error     t value     Pr(>|t|)
nameY1            45.69318724  0.5132694 89.02378209 0.000000e+00
nameY2            45.97807164  0.5132694 89.57882078 0.000000e+00
nameY1:Treat0.5    8.72325383  0.7258726 12.01760985 6.540707e-32
nameY2:Treat-0.5   8.625689    xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: The Patsy documentation (a port of R formulas to Python) may help. Particularly this section https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html. In this case, if you want the interaction not to drop any level, you have to use name:Treat -1. In your example, since you include the main effects name and Treat , the interaction drops a level of one of the variable to keep the design matrix full rank. The link I shared explains it much better than me.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the linear regression:

[image]

The `lm()` function uses QR decomposition of your model matrix X, which is created by `model.matrix()` (see [help page for lm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm)). To obtain a solution, it requires the matrix to be full-rank, basically no redundant predictor column.

So even though you indicate no intercept with `-1` , `model.matrix()` needs to ensure the model matrix is full rank so that the QR decomposition can work. We can simplify your example to:

```
value ~ name + Treat
```

Lets say we have predictors for name == Y1, name == Y2, Treat == 0.5, Treat == -0.5:

```
dummy_matrix = cbind(model.matrix(~name-1,data=dat),
                   model.matrix(~Treat-1,data=dat))

 head(dummy_matrix)
  nameY1 nameY2 Treat-0.5 Treat0.5
1      1      0         1        0
2      0      1         1        0
3      1      0         1        0
4      0      1         1        0
5      1      0         1        0
6      0      1         1        0
```

To predict something that is Y1 and Treat-0.5, it would be 1*nameY1 + 0*nameY2 + 1*Treat-0.5 + 0*Treat0.5. The last predictor is redundant because the predictor Treat-0.5 should be the difference between the two means of the groups `Treat-0.5` and `Treat-0.5`.

If we check the rank it is of course one less than the number of columns:

```
qr(dummy_matrix)$rank
[1] 3
```

And if you fit it, you get NA for the last column:

```
lm(dat$value ~ 0+dummy_matrix)

Call:
lm(formula = dat$value ~ 0 + dummy_matrix)

Coefficients:
   dummy_matrixnameY1     dummy_matrixnameY2  dummy_matrixTreat-0.5  
               54.392                 54.628                 -8.674  
 dummy_matrixTreat0.5  
                   NA
```

Hence, if you have more than 1 categorical predictor, from the 2nd categorical predictor on, one of them will be set as reference to ensure your model matrix is full rank and can be solved by QR decomposition.

You can also check this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78354/what-is-a-contrast-matrix) that discusses with examples what are contrast matrix.